# 2d games - It is safe to leave dealing with delta time on animation games especially with libgdx engine

Tags: libgdx, 2d-games

i'm new to games development

in 2d games i'm using a final delta time for all frames and for measuring speed and so on;

**i want to know if there is a problem can happen when i use final delta time instead of use counted-by-engine delta time**

and also where to use the final delta and where to use the counted one

like game in **`game.java`**

```
class game extends com.badlogic.gdx.Game {

    final float delta = 1 / 60F;

    @Override
    public void create() {
    }


    @Override
    public void render() {
        if (screen != null) screen.render(delta);
        /////////// do stuff Depended on final delta
        player.translate(150, delta)
    }
}
```

thanks :)

Comment: Safe? It won't cause a crash. But you'll have stuttering and inconsistent gameplay speed depending on what's running in the background on the device, and especially from device to device. However, for an accurate and repeatable physics simulation you do want to use a constant delta for the physics simulation while using frame time for drawing. This involves interpolating physics frames to get a smooth animation. Google "fix your timestep".

Comment: thanks @Tenfour04 this is helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use Gdx.Graphics.getDeltaTime()? The value is approximately 60, but I often see it ranging from 59 to 61.

Meant this as a comment, sorry.

Comment: also an helpful answer 
ill try to update my project to use it because as  @Tenfour04 said fixed delta time will make my game speed depended on the device speed

Answer (score 0):

In LibGDX the default frame rate is 60.

As long as the device running the application can keep up with that, a final delta of 1 / 60 will appear correct because that will be about equal to the Gdx.Graphics.getDeltaTime(). If however you either change the frame rate or the device cannot keep up with a frame rate of 60 you will get weird behavior.

Lets say it can only run at 30 frames per second, then your movement will only by 30/60 of your intended distance. So your application will slow down to half speed. Unless that was your intention, it will be a problem.

Using Gdx.Graphics.getDeltaTime() as suggested by @Ezra is usually the way to go if you want the intended movement even on a slower device.